# Database saving all the details rather than the image

Tags: android, database, image

Im writing a simple app to save contacts in a list.
My database is working fine, but when Im restarting the app or updating a contact's details(even when im not updating an image), all the Images are not visible again.

There's something I missed along the way?
Thanks in advance!

MainActivity.class

```
package org.intracode.contactmanager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //live apearences in screen objects
    EditText nameLine, PhoneLine, EmailLine, AddressLine;
    Button addBtn;
    TabHost myTab;
    List<Contact> myContactList = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView myListView;
    ImageView contactImage;
    Uri imageURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://org.intracode.contactmanager/drawable/no_logo.png");// including assigning
    DatabaseHandler contacsDB;
    ArrayAdapter<Contact> myContactsAdapter;
    int longcClickElemnt;//clicked item position
    private  static final int EDIT=0,DELETE=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //assigning line fields
        nameLine = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameLine);
        PhoneLine = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PhoneLine);
        EmailLine = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmailLine);
        AddressLine = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AdressLine);
        addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

        //assigning tab objects
        myTab = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost); //assigning general tab
        myTab.setup();
        //assigning first sub tub
        TabHost.TabSpec tabspec = myTab.newTabSpec("creator");
        tabspec.setContent(R.id.creatorTab);
        tabspec.setIndicator("Creator");//name of sub tab
        myTab.addTab(tabspec);// connecting the sub tab to the general tab
        // assigning second sub tub
        tabspec = myTab.newTabSpec("list");
        tabspec.setContent(R.id.tabContactList);
        tabspec.setIndicator("List");//name of sub tab
        myTab.addTab(tabspec);// connecting the sub tab to the general tab
        //assigning the listview object
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // assigning ImageView object
        contactImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.contactImage);
        //assignig dataBase
        contacsDB = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        //register a menu for the list object
        registerForContextMenu(myListView);
        myListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                longcClickElemnt=i;
                contactImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                return false;
            }
        });

        // name event
        nameLine.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                String email = charSequence.toString().trim();
                addBtn.setEnabled(String.valueOf(nameLine.getText()).trim().length() > 0 && isValidEmaillId(email));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        // email event
        EmailLine.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            String emailString = EmailLine.getText().toString().trim();

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                String email = charSequence.toString().trim();
                addBtn.setEnabled(nameLine.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && isValidEmaillId(email));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        //buttonEvent
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Contact newCont = new Contact(contacsDB.getContactsCount(), nameLine.getText().toString(), PhoneLine.getText().toString(), EmailLine.getText().toString(), AddressLine.getText().toString(), imageURI);
                if (!contactExist(newCont)) {
                    contacsDB.createContact(newCont);
                    myContactList.add(newCont);
                    myContactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// let  the adapter know something is changing in our list
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You added " + nameLine.getText().toString() + " to your contact list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nameLine.getText().toString() + " is already exist in your list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                nameLine.setText("");
                PhoneLine.setText("");
                EmailLine.setText("");
                AddressLine.setText("");
                contactImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_logo);


            }

        });

        //contactImageEvent
        contactImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {// defining a chooser
                Intent intent = new Intent();// intent is an object that passes a messeges in our system
                intent.setType("image/*");// Set an explicit MIME data type.
                intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//Allow the user to select a particular kind of data and return it.
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Contact Image"), 1);
            }
        });

        //populate the list such that our list view will show all the contact that in pur database
        // synchronized with our database
        if (contacsDB.getContactsCount() > 0)
            myContactList.addAll(contacsDB.getAllContacts());
        populateList();// write the contact that we added now into the list's screen
    }


    //special method for the moment that we create the menu with its fields
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu myMenu, View myView,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(myMenu,myView,menuInfo);
        myMenu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.edit_icon);
        myMenu.setHeaderTitle("Contact options");
        myMenu.add(Menu.NONE,EDIT,myMenu.NONE,"Edit contact");
        myMenu.add(Menu.NONE,DELETE,myMenu.NONE,"Delete contact");

    }

    public  boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem myItem){
        switch(myItem.getItemId()){
            case EDIT:
                Intent moveToEdit= new Intent(this,EditContactActivity.class);
                String[] argToPass={String.valueOf(myContactList.get(longcClickElemnt).getId()),myContactList.get(longcClickElemnt).getName(),
                        myContactList.get(longcClickElemnt).getPhone(), myContactList.get(longcClickElemnt).getEmail(),
                        myContactList.get(longcClickElemnt).getAddress(),String.valueOf(myContactList.get(longcClickElemnt).getImageURI())};
                moveToEdit.putExtra("args",argToPass);
                startActivityForResult(moveToEdit,2);
                break;
            case DELETE:
                //longcClickElemnt represents the position of item that we clicked on in our listview
                // , initilized every setOnItemLongClickListener
                contacsDB.deleteContact(myContactList.get(longcClickElemnt));//remove from database
                myContactList.remove(longcClickElemnt);// remove from list
                myContactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// update database instantly
                break;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(myItem);
    }
    //Handling the result of clicking the contact image(Created to reply startActivityForResult function )
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 1:// comeback from image collecting screen
                    imageURI = data.getData();
                    contactImage.setImageURI(data.getData());//Sets the content of this ImageView to the specified Uri.
                    break;
                case 2://comeback from edit contact screen
                    String[] contactDetails=data.getStringArrayExtra("result");
                    contacsDB.updateContact(new Contact(Integer.parseInt(contactDetails[0]), contactDetails[1], contactDetails[2],
                            contactDetails[3],contactDetails[4], Uri.parse(contactDetails[5])));//update datatbase operation
                    myContactList.get(longcClickElemnt).setAll(contactDetails[1], contactDetails[2],
                            contactDetails[3],contactDetails[4], Uri.parse(contactDetails[5]));
                    myContactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// update database instantly
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Changes saved!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    // special adapter that helps display data in a UI element, extending the array adapter class
    private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

        public ContactListAdapter() {
            super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.contact_layout, myContactList);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View myView, ViewGroup parent) {//adding a contact in a certain position to our contactList screen
            if (myView == null)
                myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_layout, parent, false);
            Contact currContact = myContactList.get(position);

            TextView name = myView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name_store);
            name.setText(currContact.getName());

            TextView phone = myView.findViewById(R.id.phone_store);
            phone.setText(currContact.getPhone());

            TextView email = myView.findViewById(R.id.email_store);
            email.setText(currContact.getEmail());

            TextView address = myView.findViewById(R.id.address_store);
            address.setText(currContact.getAddress());

            ImageView contactImage = myView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewOnLayput);
            contactImage.setImageURI(currContact.getImageURI());

            return myView;
        }
    }

    // write inside myListView with the help of the adapter
    private void populateList() {
        myContactsAdapter = new ContactListAdapter();
        myListView.setAdapter(myContactsAdapter);
    }

    //check if one's email address is valid
    public static boolean isValidEmaillId(String email) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    private boolean contactExist(Contact c) {
        String c_name = c.getName();
        int count = myContactList.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (myContactList.get(i).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(c_name) == 0)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

DatabaseHandler.class

```
package org.intracode.contactmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.net.Uri;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Johnny Manson on 19.01.14.
 */
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactManager",
            TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts",
            KEY_ID = "id",
            KEY_NAME = "name",
            KEY_PHONE = "phone",
            KEY_EMAIL = "email",
            KEY_ADDRESS = "address",
            KEY_IMAGEURI = "imageUri";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PHONE + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGEURI + " TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void createContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE, contact.getPhone());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, contact.getAddress());
        values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, String.valueOf(contact.getImageURI()));
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PHONE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_IMAGEURI }, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null );

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5)));
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return contact;
    }

    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getId()) });
        db.close();
    }

    public int getContactsCount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        return count;
    }

    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE, contact.getPhone());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, contact.getAddress());
        values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contact.getImageURI().toString());

        int rowsAffected = db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getId()) });
        db.close();

        return rowsAffected;
    }

    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                contacts.add(new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5))));
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

EditActivity.class

```
package org.intracode.contactmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EditContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //live appearances in screen objects
    EditText editName, editPhone, editEmail, editAddress;
    Button editButton;
    ImageView editImage;
    Uri imageURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://org.intracode.contactmanager/drawable/no_logo.png");// including assigning

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_contact);

        //assigning fields
        editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        editPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
        editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        editAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
        editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        editImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.editImage);
        // getting passed arguments
        String[] passedArg = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("args");
        editName.setText(passedArg[1]);
        editPhone.setText(passedArg[2]);
        editEmail.setText(passedArg[3]);
        editAddress.setText(passedArg[4]);
        editImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(passedArg[5]));
        //events

        editName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                String email = charSequence.toString().trim();
                editButton.setEnabled(String.valueOf(editName.getText()).trim().length() > 0 && MainActivity.isValidEmaillId(email));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        // email event
        editEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            String emailString = editEmail.getText().toString().trim();

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                String email = charSequence.toString().trim();
                editButton.setEnabled(editName.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && MainActivity.isValidEmaillId(email));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        //buttonEvent
        editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                String[] passedArg = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("args");
                String[] argToReturn = {passedArg[0], String.valueOf(editName.getText()), String.valueOf(editPhone.getText()), String.valueOf(editEmail.getText()),
                        String.valueOf(editAddress.getText()), String.valueOf(editImage)};
                returnIntent.putExtra("result", argToReturn);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        editImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {// defining a chooser
                Intent intent = new Intent();// intent is an object that passes a messeges in our system
                intent.setType("image/*");// Set an explicit MIME data type.
                intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//Allow the user to select a particular kind of data and return it.
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Contact Image"), 1);

            }
        });


    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 1:// comeback from image collecting screen
                    imageURI = data.getData();
                    editImage.setImageURI(data.getData());//Sets the content of this ImageView to the specified Uri.


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Contact class

```
package org.intracode.contactmanager;

import android.net.Uri;

import java.net.URI;

/**
 * Created by Roey on 09/08/2017.
 */

public class Contact {
    private String name ,email, phone, address;
    private Uri imageURI;
    private int id;// added for database manners


    public Contact(int id,String name ,String phone,String email,String address,Uri imageURI){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.email=email;
        this.phone=phone;
        this.address=address;
        this.imageURI=imageURI;
    }

    //getters
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }
    public String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }
    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }
    public Uri getImageURI(){
        return imageURI;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    //setters
    public void setAll(String name,String phone,String email,String address,Uri imageURI){
        this.name=name;
        this.email=email;
        this.phone=phone;
        this.address=address;
        this.imageURI=imageURI;
    }



}
```

Comment: Could you add you Contact model class.?

Comment: I think what you are asking in the body and in the title are different things. In the title looks like the images are not stored in the database, but in the body it looks like you are having issues to load the images in your application.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran I added.. realy simple

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre the problem is that the images indeed stored in the database but unfortunately, database refuses to save them somehow

Comment: Your code is fine, Did you check by printing in the log the file path..?